# Increment counter for bag data structure

Tags: c++

So I created a bag data structure, and I am attempting to increment a counter every time the same instance of a string is inserted, but for some reason my counter in never incremented even though I have 10 of the same string inputted. Suggestions?

```
struct  BagNode
{
    string dataValue;
    int dataCount;
    BagNode * next;
};
class Bag{

private:
BagNode * head;

public:
Bag()
{
    head = NULL;
    //curr = NULL;
}
void insert(string v)
{
    if(head == NULL){ //empty list
        head = new BagNode;
        head->dataValue = v;
        head->next = NULL;

    }
    else
    {
            BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
            n->dataValue = v;
            n->dataCount = 0;
            BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
            //current = head;
            if(isSame(current->dataValue,v))
            {
                n->dataCount+= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!isBefore(current->dataValue, v))        //new head
                {
                    n->next = head;
                    head = n;
                }
                else{           //mid and tail insert
                    while(current->next && isBefore(current->next->dataValue,v))
                    {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    n->next = current->next;
                    current->next = n;
                }   
            }
    }   
}
 bool isSame(string a, string b) 
 {
    transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ::tolower);
    transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), ::tolower);

    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
void traverse()
{
    BagNode * current;
    current = head;
    while(current)
    {
        output << current->dataValue << " (" << current->dataCount << ")" << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: what observation did you make when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time? You have two bugs to find: the one you're looking for, and a second one that results in a memory leak.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik may I ask where you the memory leak

Comment: Yes, you may ask. Every time an `insert()` gets called, the next statement is a `new BagNode`. No matter how the `if` statement evaluates, a `new` `BagNode` gets created. However, as you've described the problem, if the value already exists in the bag, all that has to happen is its counter gets incremented. But the code, as written, will still create a `new BagNode`, which will leak.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful. So what I should do is if the same string appears more than once, keep that same string from being inserted more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking whether you should increment on the first element of your list, and otherwise you just walk through it to figure out where to insert your new node. Keep in mind, **you never actually checked whether any of the other nodes contained the value you were supposed to be looking for**. You'll just need to fix that.

As Sam mentions above, you still have a memory leak. I'll also add that it might be better to always store the lowercase version of your string instead of recalculating every time.

Comment: Memory leak!? may I ask where I should fix that

Comment: You always create a `BagNode`, but if you find an existing element at the front, you never delete it.

Comment: oh when i do this n->next = head?

Comment: When `isSame` is true.

Comment: Does this response answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: hey I was looking at the comment about having storing the lower case version of my string instead of recalculation every time. Would I just make a temp string to store the lower case version of the original string.