# Adding Too Many Nodes

Tags: c++

I created a data bag structure, my text files consist of short stories and poems. So The first time an instance of a string is inserted, dataValue contains the string and dataCount is set to one. If another instance of that same string is inserted, dataCount is incremented. But for some reason it keeps outputting the same word over and over and all of the strings contain a count of 1 for some reason. Is there any suggestions on what I could adjust?

```
struct  BagNode
{
string dataValue;
string dataCopy;
int dataCount;
BagNode * next;
};
class Bag{
 private:
BagNode * head;
public:
Bag()
{
    head = NULL;

}
void insert(string v)
{
    if(head == NULL){ //empty list
        head = new BagNode;
        removePunct(v);
        head->dataValue = v;
        transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), ::tolower);
        head->dataCopy = v;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
            BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
            removePunct(v);
            n->dataValue = v;
            transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), ::tolower);
            n->dataCopy = v;
            BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
            n->dataCount = 1;
                if(current->dataCopy > v)
                {
                    n->next = head;
                    head = n;
                }
                else{           //mid and tail insert
                    while(current->next && current->next->dataCopy < v){
                                current = current->next;
                        }
                            //Check For Identical Strings
                            if(current->dataCopy != v)
                            {
                                n->next = current->next;
                                current->next = n;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                current->dataCount++;
                            }

                    }
            }   

    }
```

> Output: 10Annette (1) 1805 (1) 7 (1) a (1) a (1) a (1) a (1) a (1) a (1) All (1) all (1) an (1) and (1) and (1) and (1) and (1) and (1) and (1) and (4) Anna (1) Anna (1) AntichristI (1) AntichristI (1) are (1) are (1) arrive (1) as (1) as (1) as (1) at (1) attack (1) be (1) being (1) believe (1) better (1) between (1) Buonapartes (1) But (1) But (1) by (1) by (1) by (1) call (1)

Comment: You created, my <expletive deleted>. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479560/debug-time-issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477141/c-linked-list-node-counting-need-help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457116/increment-counter-for-bag-data-structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520003/removing-certain-nodes  A couple more that have been deleted or I can't find anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to create a linked list of all the strings and finding their count ? Are you trying to create a linked list sorted based on the occurence of the strings ?